# Can I use this hard drive model in my late 2011 Mac Mini?

Tags: mac, hard-drive

I suspect my Mac Mini (late) 2011 having some bad blocks, most of the hard drive has them it seems. I told this to my friend and he said he can give me a hard drive that he no longer needs, it was previously what he was going to use on another laptop he had, but no longer needs it.

In any case, my question is if I could safely use this hard drive in my Mac Mini 2011. It's a "Fujitsu model MHV2120BH 120.0GB", it's a SATA hard drive. I can't really provide any more info, since he doesn't have the original box or anything, just the hard drive itself.

Any help is appreciated, if possible please also provide reference. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed your post did not include the drive size. The Mac Mini will support any laptop sata drive (2.5 inch).

EDIT: Totally did not see the model number in your post before. Yeah it will fit fine (according to newegg its a 2.5in sata drive). Here is a link to ifixit where you can see the installed drives form factor and instructions.

http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+Mac+Mini+Mid+2011+Hard+Drive+Replacement/6422/3

Comment: Note that according to your sources, not just any 2.5 drive will work, only those with a SATA interface. Those with an IDE interface won't fit. Please correct your answer to reflect this.